# Is it possible to create a unique variable in react using uuid and pass that into sass?

Tags: sass, styling, react-tsx

I am wondering if it's possible to create a unique variable that I can then append onto classNames for my react components and also pass into the Sass styling file to target those specific components.

This unique variable will be generated each time I run the app

I have tried looking online with multiple different phrases to see if I can find any proper examples, but haven't had any luck in the past hour. So, curious to know if this is even possible.

I am trying to achieve this through ReactTs and Sass alone.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Yes, you can generate a guid with javascript and inject it with sass-loader and append it to class names in your scss rules. But maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: I am trying to create a template for extensions that I can base my future work off of, I want there to be a randomly generated guid that I can use to uniquely style my extensions. Just to ensure there's no chance of the extension or page styles clashing with each other

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules):

**styles.modules.scss**

```scss
.myClass {
  // ...
}
```

**Component.tsx**

```js
import styles from "./styles.modules.scss";

const MyComponent = () => (
  <div className={styles.myClass}>
    {/* ... */}
  </div>
);
```

Support and implementation of CSS Modules will depend on what tool you use to run your app.